# OpenVPN: client pushing route to server?

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I have a situation like this:

- Server with 2 IP addresses: SIP1 and SIP2
- Client with 2 IP addresses: CIP1 and CIP2

On SIP2 I have started OpenVPN server, and I connect to it from Client, using --client option to OpenVPN to bind traffic to CIP2

Now the qustion - how can I modify routing table on Server, to add route to SIP1 via tunnel when Client connects?

Comment: Are you looking for a site-to-site configuration?

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to modify the routing table on the server.  If you want the client to have a route through the tunnel to SIP1, that makes sense.  Otherwise I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make sure any access from Server to Client daemons that listen on CIP1 goes through tunnel.

Comment: Why not just talk to the client over it's VPN address?

Comment: Because I don't want to change settings in applications that use it. That's first. And second - instead of CIP2, I might have CLIENT_NETWORK_2 - and I will still need the same solution.

Comment: When you connect the client to the server, you'll have an additional IP on the tun/tap device created on the client.  You should be able to reach that IP address from the server, so I don't think you need to add more routing rules.  If you use bridging mode, you should have no problems reaching the client from the server.  If your server has 2 IPs, and it's trying to reach the client IP of the tun/tap address, the server routing table will already know how to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all just speculation, but...

It looks like you might be able to use the `client-connect` script to do what you want. From the man page:

```
The script is passed the common name and  IP  address  of
the just-authenticated  client as environmental variables
(see environmental variable sec- tion below).  The script is
also passed the pathname of a not-yet-created temporary file
as $1  (i.e.  the  first  command line argument), to be used
by the script to pass dynamically generated config file
directives back to OpenVPN.
```

So, using this script, you should be able to add the necessary route commands to the OpenVPN configuration.  There is a corresponding `client-disconnect` script you can use to tear down the route.

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is typical server-to-server [ rather than dialup-alike ] setup.

on the server side put something as follows:

```
# first local address assigned to the vpn tunnel, then remote
# [ this is not SIPx/CIPx - it's just private addressing for the tunnel ]
ifconfig 10.255.255.10 10.255.255.9
# here you install a new route on the server whenever vpn is established
# you want to put CIP1/32 routed via vpn ip assigned to the remote end of vpn
route 10.13.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.255.255.9
port somePort
[..]
```

on the client side:

```
# put your SIP1 here and some port on which server is configured
remote 213.xxx.xxx.xxx somePort
# again - first is local, second - remote address of vpn tunnel 
ifconfig 10.255.255.9 10.255.255.10
# you want to put below SIP1/32 routed via vpn ip from far end of the tunnel
route 10.15.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.255.255.10
```

you will need to add to those few lines specific to your encryption method. try for starters pre-shared key as described [here](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html). it'll be more secure if you use proper tls for production setup.

since you'll inject SIP1/32 [ SIP1 255.255.255.255 in notation used in openvpn ] - your secure route - as soon as vpn is established - will always be chosen for communication to SIP1 [ and vice versa ].
but.. as soon as vpn goes doen - possibly sensitive traffic will flow via untrusted network. which.. you do not want to happen. if you do have to use public SIP1 / CIP1 - make sure firewalls [even the local ones] allow only communication over the tunX devices created by openvpn and do not let any direct traffic on public internet.

Answer (score 0):

**route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0**  #to direct packets to the OVPN TUN interface

**iroute x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0** #in the user configuration script 
                             specified by client-config-dir command to add 
                             routing inside OVPN process